# Как сделать дату формата `13 июнь 1998` через php?

Tags: php

Как сделать дакой дата `13 июнь 1998` через php? У меня сейчас такой код

```
<?php
$date="897696000";
echo date('d.m.Y', $date);
?>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<?php
$date="897696000";
$Month_rus = array('Январь', 'Февраль', 'Март', 'Апрель', 'Май', 'Июнь', 'Июль', 'Август', 'Сентябрь', 'Октябрь', 'Ноябрь', 'Декабрь');
$date = date('d', $date) . ' ' . $Month_rus[ date('n', $date) - 1 ] . ' ' . date('Y', $date);
echo $date;
?>
```

Comment: Универсальный способ.

Comment: @Visman конечно. по другим способам нас опередили пока расписывали ответ =)

Answer (score 3):

Вот что нужно сделать с функцией strftime(), чтобы под Windows увидеть название месяца на русском и в UTF-8

```
$date="897696000";

$locale_time = setlocale (LC_TIME, 'ru_RU.UTF-8', 'Rus');

function strf_time($format, $timestamp, $locale)
{
    $date_str = strftime($format, $timestamp);
    if (strpos($locale, '1251') !== false)
        {
            return iconv('cp1251', 'utf-8', $date_str);
        }
        else
        {
            return $date_str;
        }
}

echo strf_time('%d %B %Y', $date, $locale_time);
```

P.S. Компиляция по мотивам интернета.

Comment: Уточнение: ОС Win 7 32бит.

Comment: +1 за решение на windows, скорее всего обществу будет также полезно видеть Вам ответ и на анг версии.

Comment: @Alex, а вдруг не везде работает !? ;)

Comment: на win 7 64 также выводится нужная дата

Comment: [здесь](http://php.net/manual/ru/function.setlocale.php#118076) более расширенный fix для Windows.

Comment: @Alex, а разве у русскоязычной винды была кодировка cp1252? Это кажется расширенная латиница?

Comment: она более известна как latin1, таблица кириллических букв находится в ней на месте арабских символов.

Answer (score 2):

Например так:

```
<?php
setlocale(LC_TIME, 'ru_RU.UTF-8');
echo date('d F Y', $date);
```

**Добавлено**

С `date()` я поспешил. Она не работает с локалью. Используйте `strftime()`.

```
<?php
setlocale(LC_TIME, 'ru_RU.UTF-8');
$date="897696000";
echo strftime('%d %B %Y', $date);
```

Comment: `setlocale` и работает не везде.

Comment: @Visman +1 да прав.

Comment: @Visman Где именно не работает? Может неправильно локаль прописываете или кодировка не поддерживается. В Windows, например, свой формат описания локали.

Comment: @tutankhamun, на винде локаль 'ru_RU.UTF-8' не находит, а локаль 'rus' возвращает название месяца в кодировке win-1251.

Comment: @Visman проблема в windows уже обсуждалась [здесь](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18513742/ru-ru-russian-setlocale-not-working-on-date-and-time), решение есть(если только это можно назвать решением т.к. кодировка страницы будет в 1251).

Comment: @Alex, тот принятый ответ дает на моей Win-7 название месяца на инглише.

Comment: @Visman [ответ по проблеме в windows](http://stackoverflow.com/a/18537989/5398808) работает на win7 64, выводит "вторник, Октябрь 13" (проверили)

Comment: @Alex, значит `win7 64` поддерживает локаль 'ru_RU.UTF-8' Или может еще зависит от издания (домашняя, про и так далее).

Answer (score 1):

Использовать:

```
string date ( string $format [, int $timestamp = time() ] )
```

В переменную `$format`задать нужный формат даты